# how to change an ADO.net database due to server change

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ado.net

I'm working on a project using mvc 4 .net and we are using an ADO.net entity data model in order to access our database. The project was originally developed in a different computer than mine, so the server name is different. Because of that, I can´t access the database so, I tried changing the connection string, I put my server name and my database name ( the same as in the other computer) I changed the identification method for windows identification because that´s the method my computer uses. However I'm still getting errors. Is there some kind of wizard that allows me to change the database in an ADO.net object? Or the only way is modifying the connection string?

This is my connection string

```
<add name="SOMEEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-SOURCE-SERVER;initial catalog=SOME; integrated security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And this is the original

```
<add name="SOMEEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.SOMEDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OTHER-DUDE-SERVER;initial catalog=SOME;persist security info=True;user id=SOME;password=SOME;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The exception type is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

And the stacktrace (a big one)

> StackTrace:
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>               in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               in System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>               in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>               in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>               in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               in System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)

Comment: "However Im still getting errors." - and they are?

Comment: silly me, give me a minute

Comment: Does you Windows account have access to this new database?

Comment: Well, I'm working locally  if that's what you mean. I use windows authentication

Comment: in previous connection string you were using "user" login to SQL but now you're changing authentication to windows thats why it's not working